# Unable to install Linux in a PC with Windows 10

Tags: linux, boot, grub, grub2

This is my problem:

I have a netbook PC with this issues:

> Lenovo ideapad 320
>
> CPU: Dual Core Intel Celeron N3350
>
> RAM: 4 Gb
>
> Hard disk SSD SATA 500 Gb

This computer is running Windows 10, and I want to install Linux. My choose, after try some light distros and live versions, is [Lithium](https://www.bunsenlabs.org/), Debian based.

Before to do that, the hard disk had three partitions (I think). One for Windows, antoher one for recovery and the last one for something related with Lenovo. Before to install linux, I made a repartition of the SSD. Then I created a `/dev/sda6`, for mount `/`, `dev/sda7`, for mount `/home` y `dev/sda8` for swapping.

The instalation of linux always give me an error when I install GRUB, stopping the process in this step. After some attempts, I try to do that from Windows with [Grub2Win](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/) tool, getting a bootable menu. Then I define a Linux entry with `/dev/sda6` partition (where I have mounted `/`). Therefore, when I try to enter to Linux from this menu created by Grub2Win, I get an error and I get the [(initramfs)](https://www.google.com/search?q=initramfs%20ubuntu%20stack%20overflow&client=firefox-b-e&sxsrf=AOaemvKehGAHJC9jtn4cGI202pCNQFDUWw%3A1641147433260&ei=KezRYcGcD6z87_UPqK27sAY&oq=initramfs%20%3A%20stac&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIGCAAQFhAeMggIABAWEAoQHjoHCAAQRxCwAzoHCAAQsAMQQzoECAAQQzoFCAAQgAQ6BQgAEMsBSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUL0FWMsRYJ4jaAFwAngAgAF8iAH0BZIBAzEuNpgBAKABAcgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) prompt.

From Linux in *live* mode, and running `GParted`, this is like I have the SSD:

```
Partition|Name                        |File System|Label     |Size      |Flags
/dev/sda1|EFI system partition        |fat32      |SYSTEM_DRV|260 MiB    |boot,esp
/dev/sda2|Microsoft reserved partition|unknow     |   ---    |16 MiB     |msftres
/dev/sda3|Basic data partition        |ntfs       |Windows   |263.73 GiB |msftdata
/dev/sda4|Basic data partition        |ntfs       |LENOVO    |25.00  GiB |msftdata
/dev/sda5|Basic data partition        |ntfs       |WINRE_DRV |1000.00 MiB|hidden, diag
/dev/sda6|                            |ext4       |          |46.57 GiB  |boot,esp
/dev/sda7|                            |ext4       |          |111.76 GiB |
/dev/sda8|                            |linux-swap |          |17.46 GiB  |
```

On the other hand, in the BIOS I have UEFI mode and Secure Boot disabled and this appears in the beginning:

```
Grub2Win EFI - 64 Bit (WDC WD5000LPCX -24VHATO)
Windows Boot Manager (WDC WD5000LPCX -24VHATO)
```

I have no idea what can I do.

Comment: On Ubuntu, one should leave UEFI and Secure Boot enabled, though I haven't tried Lithium.  However, Fast Boot in BIOS/UEFI, and Fast Startup in Windows should be disabled to allow dual boot.

Comment: No one knows what `an error` is.

Answer (score 0):

well if your grub is having issues it would be a better idea for you to figure out what went wrong because I have been using grub since when I first started using linux (I use arch btw) and had almost no issues. I am suspecting that you forgot to made a partition for EFI. It should be 300MB and formatted as fat32 (`mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/[efi partition]`). I suggest you to do that first, install `grub` and `efibootloader` and do `grub-install —-target=x86_64-efi —-efi-directory=[esp] —-bootloader-id=[whatever you name the bootloader]` where [esp] is the mountpoint of your  EFI partition (should be at /boot in your base system) and [whatever you name the bootloader] is self explanatory, just use underscore to replace space if there is any. After that you should tell grub to add your installed system into bootloader entry. do `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/EFI/grub/grub.cfg`.

disclaimer: this is what I do in arch linux and might not work for you depending on various reasons. do adjustments for yourself if needed

Comment: I'm not truly sure. I have an EFI partition in /dev/sda1. May I create another one for doing the grub operations you describe me? Thank you very much!